# Need last 30 days of data in library database

Tags: sql

I need the magazines that were added to this database for the last 30 days. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT A.TITLE, A.EDITION, B.DONATEDBY, B.DATE_ADDED
FROM LIBRARY A
JOIN LIB_COPIES B ON A.IDNO=B.IDNO
WHERE A.TYPE LIKE '%Magazine%'
  AND B.DONATEDBY LIKE '%State%'
  AND B.DATE_ADDED>CURRENT_DATE-31 
ORDER BY B.DATE_ADDED
```

It doesn't get any entries from today's date.

I have tried

```
DATEDIFF(dateColumn, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
AND >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

I am new to this forgive me if in wrong format. I put `B.Date_added` for that is my column, where I felt it should be.

Please help me!

Comment: Hi Joyce - welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure there is data in LIB_COPIES that meet your where condition? If not, you are doing an inner join which will come back with zilch.

Comment: Could you tell us which SQL database you're using (ie. Microsoft SQL Server), the schema for tables `library` and `lib_copies`, and a sample of the rows you're trying to query?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using MySQL, `CURRENT_DATE-31` does not subtract 31 days from the current date. Instead it converts `CURRENT_DATE` to an integer and subtracts 31.

```
select CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - 31;

CURRENT_DATE    CURRENT_DATE - 31
2020-01-10      20200079
```

Instead, use [`date_sub(current_date, interval 31 day)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

```
select CURRENT_DATE, date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 31 day);

CURRENT_DATE    date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 31 day)
2020-01-10      2019-12-10
```

Or if you mean 1 month, use `interval 1 month`.

---

`DATEDIFF(dateColumn,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 30` does not work because when `dateColumn` is in the past the diff will be negative.

```
select DATEDIFF("2020-01-01",current_date);

DATEDIFF("2020-01-01",current_date)
-9
```

Instead, reverse the order of the dates.

```
select DATEDIFF(current_date, "2020-01-01")

DATEDIFF(current_date, "2020-01-01")
9
```